# Can I get tourist visa on arrival at Dubai airport?

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens, dubai, visas-on-arrival, dxb

I am a Pakistani from Saudi Arabia, I want to visit Dubai for 2 days.

So I get air ticket from Saudi Arabia to Dubai. Can I get visa on arrival in Dubai or Sharja airport to stay there for 2 days?

Comment: Is your final destination Dubai, or are you just there for a few hours on your way elsewhere? Transit Visas normally aren't issued for days-long trips, those normally need tourist visas

Comment: my final destination is dubai i will travel to dubai from dammam and come back here i just want to spend 2 nights there

Answer (score 3):

Nationals of Pakistan are not eligible for a [UAE tourist visa on arrival](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx). You will need to obtain a visa in advance.

You [can](https://www.dubaivisa.net/EK-OnlineVisa/Countries.aspx) apply for your visa online. After you have booked your flight with Emirates, go to [Manage your booking](http://www.emirates.com/SessionHandler.aspx?pub=/english&pageurl=/MYB.aspx&section=MYB) to apply for the visa. When you apply this way, you [do not need a visa stamp](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx) on your passport.

You can also apply the traditional way, through the UAE embassy or consulate serving the area where you reside (e.g. in Riyadh or Jeddah).

Answer (score 1):

If you have permanent residency in Saudi Arabia (ie, an iqama) you need to apply online at [this website](https://ednrd.ae/GCCIND/createVisa.do) - as GCC permanent residents can get a visa to Dubai.

As of October, on arrival visas have been stopped in favor of the online application.